# SSD caching via Intel SRT and NAS backups, do they cause problems?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, ssd, nas, cache

I'm wanting to put an SSD as a cache drive using Intel's SRT technology, but am wondering, will running backups throughout the day from my NAS will cause the cache drive to constantly flush out games and other files I actually use regularly?

In my particular case, it would be a 64GB SSD cache vs a 4TB filesystem with about 3.2TB of backed up data. And I'm talking about a clearly data storage and application drive, no OS.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope**, it's "smart"-er than that.

As [mentioned here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/smart-response-technology.html), SRT "caches data...that benefit the most from acceleration".